# print excel as pdf command button

Tags: excel, pdf, save

I have an excel file that I want to have on the main worksheet a button to say "print as PDF" but without saving or opening, only printing. Do you have any code for that? may thanks

Comment: Why would you want to print an Excel file as a PDF? Why not print it directly instead of converting to a PDF first? The printout looks the same. Or do you mean **print to** instead of **print as**? *Print to* creates a PDF file by sending it to a PDF print driver. *Print as* means create a PDF file and send it to an actual printer. Clearly they're not the same thing.

Comment: One way would be to switch the default print driver to PDF, then simply print the Excel file. What have you tried so far? What have you searched for?

Comment: You're right, I didn't realise pdf and excel printouts would look the same. Sorted now thanks a lot